# Creating a fake point light with a normal map and empty game object

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting, shader-nodes, normal-map

I'm trying to create a fake point light using a empty game object to have complete control of the color and shading. I get it to work pretty well using high-poly geometry by calculating the dot product of the surface normal and the position of the empty. So this is pretty much the effect I'm trying to create.

[image]

This is for a game project, so I want to use a normal map for performance reasons, but here things break down completely. When I move the empty around the light mask fills up with a linear gradient and the "light" direction seems wrong as well.

[image]

Here's my normal map and my node setup. What am I doing wrong? Please help :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your Image Texture Color Space should be set to Non-Color, not sRGB, but I wonder if your normal map colors are correct?

Comment: Yes, your Normal map colours seem off. Areas perpendicular to the surface should have a pink colour, not the angled ones as in your Normal. Try baking your Normal map again.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's been Non-Color, it's just annoying that Blender always resets it to sRGB whenever you change textures. I've tried so many different ways of creating the normal map, but it always ends up looking a bit off. I now tried taking an extra step and generating it in Substance designer and converted it to a World space normal map and now it seem to work. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

For a normal map your *Image Texture* color space should be set to *Non-Color*, not *sRG*.